# How to open a new dialog windows and focus on old windows using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to open a new dialog windows and focus on old windows using javascript ?

This is my code , when click link its open dialog windows.

When click link and open dialog, I want to focus on old windows.

How can I do that ?

https://jsfiddle.net/aqhqmk6m/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>;
(function ($) {
    $.fn.customerPopup = function (e, intWidth, intHeight, blnResize) {
        e.preventDefault();
        intWidth = intWidth || '500';
        intHeight = intHeight || '400';
        strResize = blnResize ? 'yes' : 'no';
        var strTitle = typeof this.attr('title') !== 'undefined' ? this.attr('title') : 'Social Share', strParam = 'width=' + intWidth + ',height=' + intHeight + ',resizable=' + strResize, objWindow = window.open(this.attr('href'), strTitle, strParam).focus();
    };
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.xxx').on('click', function (e) {
            $(this).customerPopup(e);
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
//# sourceURL=pen.js
</script>

<a class="xxx" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
test
</a>
```

Comment: You can use the window.opener() method - which allows interaction of the window that is opened to then interact with the window that opened it - eg (without using your code)

Comment: @gavgrif -- Could you please show me some fiddle please.